# Binding chart LegendItem checkbox to series visibility in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, charts, wpftoolkit

My WPFToolKit chart contains a few series.  I've templated the legend itself, and also templated the LegendItem by creating a style resource:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomLegendItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type charting:LegendItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charting:LegendItem}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Background}" Stroke="{Binding Background}" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,0,3,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Visibility,Converter={StaticResource VisToBoolConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="(num)" />
                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="10 0" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineSeries}">
    <Setter Property="LegendItemStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomLegendItemStyle}" />
</Style>
```

This creates a checkbox in the LegendItem, which is supposed to be controlling the visibility of the series.  But it doesn't.  I've created properties on the ViewModel too (which default to true/visible), and which the LineSeries Visibility binds to

```
<charting:LineSeries ... Visibility="{Binding DisplayLoad,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

But the two don't hook up.  If I change the checkbox binding path to StoopidUser, I get a binding error in the output window telling me that StoopidUser property not found on object `LineDataPoint`, which has me a bit stumped.  I've checked right through and can't see (a) why it's a LineDataPoint (b) how to get to the series from it.

Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Finally I was able to make it. 
Here is my solution.
[image]

```
    <PointCollection x:Key="Serie1Key">1,10 2,20 3,30 4,40</PointCollection>
    <PointCollection x:Key="Serie2Key">2,10 4,20 6,30 8,40</PointCollection>

    <Style x:Key="CustomLegendItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LegendItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Owner.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBoolConverter}}" />
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="8" Height="8" Fill="{Binding Background}" Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                        <visualizationToolkit:Title VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Chart Title" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="X" IndependentValuePath="Y" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Serie1Key}" LegendItemStyle="{StaticResource CustomLegendItemStyle}"/>
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="X" IndependentValuePath="Y" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Serie2Key}" LegendItemStyle="{StaticResource CustomLegendItemStyle}"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have a `Visible` property in my objects passed to `LineSeries`' `ItemsSource` so that I can individually hide each line in the graph. I only need to somehow bind it to the `LegendItem`'s so that is is hidden as well (it is odd to not show the line but have it in the legend).

Answer (score 0):

I never figured this out exactly.  But removing the legend and putting my own there provided me with the opportunity to bind as I expected it to work.  Would still like to know where I was wrong though if anyone ever finds out...